# Is it bad practice to initialize a pointer to nullptr, and then allocate memory to it later based on if conditions?

Tags: c++

I have two questions about the following program:

1. In `function`, is it bad practice to initialize a pointer to `nullptr` (`MyClass* mcPtr = nullptr;`) and then allocate memory to it later in an `if-else` branch like this? Am I re-allocating in this case?
2. The syntax of the `new` during dynamic memory allocation: where is this syntax documented, where I pass in an object to `new MyClass`? ie, `new MyClass(MyClass::get("abc"))` receives a `MyClass` object `MyClass::get("abc")` as the input? I thought `new` must take in the actual inputs of the constructor?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MyClass {
protected:
    explicit MyClass(string input): input_(input){}
public:
    //builders
    static MyClass get(string input){
        return MyClass(input);
    }
    static MyClass getHardCoded(){
        return MyClass("hardcoded");
    }

    //getter
    const string& getInput() const {
        return input_;
    }
private:
    string input_;
};

void function(bool toHardCode)
{
    MyClass* mcPtr = nullptr;
    if (toHardCode){
        mcPtr = new MyClass(MyClass::getHardCoded());
    } else {
        mcPtr = new MyClass(MyClass::get("abc"));
    }
    cout<<"MyClass input is: "<<mcPtr->getInput()<<endl;
    delete mcPtr;
}

int main(){
    function(true); // output: "MyClass input is: hardcoded"
    function(false);// output: "MyClass input is: abc"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Answer: no. Initializing all variables is good practice. It prevents variables with automatic storage duration from ever holding indeterminate values. If you initialize a pointer to `nullptr`, then you can validate whether it is set or not simply with `if (mypointer)`. If you fail to initialize it to `nullptr`, referencing it would result in undefined behavior. That said, compilers have gotten much better issuing diagnostics if you attempt to use a variable that has not been initialized (also depends on the warnings you enable). It's an academic point, but initializing prevents code errors.

Comment: Better still, make `mcPtr` a `std::unique_ptr<MyClass>`

Comment: If you're concerned about performance here, any sane compiler will probably optimise that anyway. There is no downside to initialising your variable.

Comment: Manually calling `new` and `delete` is bad practice (unless you're writing your own container or smart pointer), use `unique_ptr`. Also, one question per question.

Comment: In the expression `new MyClass(MyClass::get("abc"));` an object of type `MyClass` is created on the heap, initialized by (implicitly defined) move constructor from the return value of `MyClass::get("abc")` call. In this example, the `MyClass` object doesn't actually need to be allocated on the heap; I assume you are doing it for learning purposes.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin so there's no problem with initializing a pointer to nullptr then re-allocating its memory to something else as the code does ?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik so new MyClass(<moved MyClass object>) ? will that avoid copying the MyClass object ?

Comment: @user1008636 100% correct. Remember, a pointer is simply a normal variable that holds the address for something else as its value. Just as you can initialize `int a = 0;` and then set `a = 5;` your can initialize `char *mypointer = nullptr;` and then assign a new address with `mypointer = new XXX;` Exactly the same. You are simply assigning a new value to a variable.

Comment: I consider this is opinion-based.   While a lot of people advocate it, initialising all pointers to `nullptr` is pointless for those pointers where the first subsequent operation is reinitialising it to something else (e.g. result of a `new` expression, address of a variable, etc).   For that reason, a *competing opinion* is to avoid creating a pointer before it is needed, and before information is available to initialise it. For example, instead of `Type *p = nullptr; a_lot_of_code_that_does_not_touch_p(); p = new Type;` do `a_lot_of_code_that_does_not_touch_p(); Type *p = new Type;`

Comment: Manual new/delete is bad coding in most cases. It introduces memory safety issues and is not the modern C++ way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1. First question:

In general, it's good practice in C/C++ to set any **empty** pointer to `nullptr`, because when you dereference a `nullptr` you'll get an error so you can more easily trace where the problem is, than when the pointer has some garbage  value (any empty pointer has some garbage value except if you assign it to nullptr).

## 2. Second question:

```
new MyClass(MyClass::get("abc"))
```

Here you are making the following :

- Call `MyClass::get("abc")` and return a temp object, let's call it `x`
- Pass `x` to `MyClass` (`MyClass(x)`), so you call the copy/move constructor of a new object which is passed to `new` syntax

## 3. Tips:

- Your code uses the factory pattern (more information: [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/factory-method-for-designing-pattern/), [Fluent{C++}](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2022/06/05/design-patterns-vs-design-principles-factory-method/))
- The compiler may avoid the extra copy in the second question ([Copy Elision](https://web.archive.org/web/20140113221447/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/))

Comment: _"when you dereference a `nullptr` you'll get an error"_  Technically, dereferencing a nullptr is undefined behaviour.  A standard-conforming implementation does not have to produce an error.

Comment: GeeksForGeeks is a terrible site to reference. It is packed with misinformation, bad practices and broken code.